# Symfony 3 multiple entities in one form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-3.1

I stuck with this for past two days. I am creating bus traveling website. Currently I am in phase of adding new bus to database.

One bus (or all of them) have many amenities (like AirCon, WiFi, Kitchen, ...) and each of these needs to have custom prices. Let says that our bus have AirCon. AirCon for this bus will cost 50 USD but for other bus AirCon might cost 100 USD. To do that I created 3 Entities (Bus Vehicles Entity, Amenities Entity and Bus Vehicles Amenities Entity). Inside Amenities Entity I iwll store Id of bus, ID of amenity and price for that amenity for that bus ID.

Problem is that I can't get it work. I got blank HTML element when rendering form for that field.I can't add or delete multiple amenities and I am not sure why it is not working.

Does someone knows where is the problem?

Here is the code that I use:

Amenities Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Amenities
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="amenities", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="administrator_id", columns={"administrator_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Amenities
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $createdAt = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="modified_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $modifiedAt = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="administrator_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $administrator;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BusVehiclesAmenities", mappedBy="amenities")
     */
    private $amenities;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Amenities
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return Amenities
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->amenities = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * Add amenities
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities $amenities
     * @return Amenities
     */
    public function addAmenities(BusVehiclesAmenities $amenities)
    {
        $this->amenities[] = $amenities;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove amenities
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities $amenities
     */
    public function removeAmenities(BusVehiclesAmenities $amenities)
    {
        $this->amenities->removeElement($amenities);
    }

    /**
     * Get amenities_bus_vehicles
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getAmenities()
    {
        return $this->amenities;
    }

}
```

Bus Vehicles Entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * BusVehicles
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="bus_vehicles", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="company_id", columns={"company_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="bus_type", columns={"bus_type"}), @ORM\Index(name="fuel_type", columns={"fuel_type"}), @ORM\Index(name="emission_class", columns={"emission_class"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BusVehicles
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="licence_plate", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $licencePlate;



    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Companies
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Companies")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\BusTypes
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BusTypes", inversedBy="busType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bus_type", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BusVehiclesAmenities", mappedBy="bus")
     */
    private $busVehiclesAmenities;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->busVehiclesAmenities = new ArrayCollection();
    }




    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add busVehiclesAmenities
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities busVehiclesAmenities
     * @return BusVehicles
     */
    public function addBusVehiclesAmenities(BusVehiclesAmenities $busVehiclesAmenities)
    {
        $this->busVehiclesAmenities[] = $busVehiclesAmenities;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove busVehiclesAmenities
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities $busVehiclesAmenities
     */
    public function removeBusVehiclesAmenities(BusVehiclesAmenities $busVehiclesAmenities)
    {
        $this->busVehiclesAmenities->removeElement($busVehiclesAmenities);

    }
    /**
     * Get busVehiclesAmenities
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getBusVehiclesAmenities()
    {
        return $this->busVehiclesAmenities;

    }


    /**
     * Set licencePlate
     *
     * @param string $licencePlate
     *
     * @return BusVehicles
     */
    public function setLicencePlate($licencePlate)
    {
        $this->licencePlate = $licencePlate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set company
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Companies $company
     *
     * @return BusVehicles
     */
    public function setCompany(Companies $company = null)
    {
        $this->company = $company;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get company
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Companies
     */
    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }



}
```

Bus Amenities Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * BusVehiclesAmenities
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="bus_vehicles_amenities", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="amenities_id", columns={"amenities_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="bus_id", columns={"bus_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BusVehiclesAmenities
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BusVehicles", inversedBy="busVehiclesAmenities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bus_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     */
    private $bus;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Amenities", inversedBy="amenities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="amenities_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     */
    private $amenities;

    /**
     * @var float
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float", scale=2)
     */
    protected $price;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set Bus
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehicles
     *
     * @return BusVehiclesAmenities
     */
    public function setBus($bus)
    {
        $this->bus = $bus;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get busId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getBus()
    {
        return $this->bus;
    }

    /**
     * Set amenities
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Amenities
     *
     * @return BusVehiclesAmenities
     */
    public function setAmenities($amenities)
    {
        $this->amenities = $amenities;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get amenities
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Amenities
     */
    public function getAmenities()
    {
        return $this->amenities;
    }
    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param float $price
     *
     * @return BusVehiclesAmenities
     */
    public function sePrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }
}
```

FORMS:

Add new bus form:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Form\Type;

use AdminBundle\Form\Type\BusVehiclesAmenitiesType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;




class BusVehiclesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('licencePlate')
            ->add('company', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Companies',
                'choice_label' => 'name',

            ->add('busVehiclesAmenities', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'   => BusVehiclesAmenitiesType::class,
                'allow_add'    => true,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\BusVehicles'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'adminbundle_busvehicles';
    }


}
```

Bus Vehicles Amenities Form

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\BusVehiclesAmenities;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class BusVehiclesAmenitiesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('price', MoneyType::class, array(
             'scale' => 2,
            ))
            ->add('amenities', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' =>'AppBundle:Amenities',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ))
        ;

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => BusVehiclesAmenities::class
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_busvehiclesamenities';
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the entity classes for form binding. 
I would create a new class, (e.g. BusVehicle) which contains all properties that need to be on the form (particular fields) and use that as the 'data_class'. This way you would not only solve your problem, but you would also decouple presentation layer from business layer (see [Multitier Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)).

I usually put these classes in `Form/Model` directory.

In your case the class would be `Form/Model/BusVehicle`, and it would have `$amenities` property.
The amenities would be an array of `Form/Model/Amenity` objects.

You would probably need to use [embedded forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) just don't use entity classes as 'data_object'. After a successful bind, you instantiate and populate entities for persist or update.

And you don't need the third entity ("Bus Vehicles Amenities").